# Magento2 multi-store on different domain

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore

I have created a `sub-website`, `sub-store`, and `sub-store-view` from magento2 admin and update sub-store `base url` from configuration setting.

After that I have created a subdomain (`sub.example.com`), but here I am little confused that subdomain will link to root directory or any sub directory, and what changes I have to make in index.php and .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created successfully sub website in magento2, steps are as follows  :

1) Create "Sub Website/Sub Store/ Sub Store View" from admin panel.

2) Update configuration setting :

```
base Url (http://sub.example.com/)
Link Url (http://sub.example.com/)
Static Url (http://example.com/pub/static/)
Media Url (http://example.com/pub/media/)
```

3) Create a sub directory 'sub' in magento root directory and point "sub domain (sub.example.com)" to this directory.

4) Copy `index.php` and `.htaccess` to this directory from root and made two changes in `index.php`

```
i) replace "/app/bootstrap.php" to "/../app/bootstrap.php"

ii) replace
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); 

to 

$params = $_SERVER;$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = "sub";
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = "website"; 
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update root/pub index.php file after created stores and set domain for stores and websites**

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
//$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
//$bootstrap->run($app);
$params = $_SERVER;
$host = $params['HTTP_HOST'];

if($host == "{domain1.com}")
{
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '{website_code1}';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
}

else if($host == "{domain2.com}")
{
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '{website_code2}'; // Website Code
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; // website
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
}
elseif($host == "{domain3.com}") // For specific store view domain 
{   
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = '{storeview_code1}'; // Store view code
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store'; // For Store
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
}
else
{
    $params = $_SERVER;
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base';
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
}
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update index.php in your magento root:

Replace:

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

with the following code:

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'www.domain.co.uk':
        $params = $_SERVER; $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'uk-store-code'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
        $bootstrap->run($app); 
        break; 
    case 'www.domain.fr':
        $params = $_SERVER; $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'fr-store-code'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
        $bootstrap->run($app); 
    break; 

    default: 
        Mage::run(); 
    break; 
}
```